# Generate a point chart from XML data, possibly with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, charts

I would like to generate some point chart from XML data.

The data should be grouped using color by its "id" attribute. The position is stored in "x" and "y". What software should I use? I tried Excel but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: That url gives We can't show you that page

Comment: I see some macro here http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/343380.html

Answer (score 2):

You could open the XML file using Excel (there is an [*Import* function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx) hidden in the developer tab).

Afterwards you could generate a scatter plot like it's showed on one of the following websites:

- [Excel Scatter Chart](http://www.excel-2010.com/excel-scatter-chart/)
- [Teach Project: Using Excel to Make a Scatter Plot](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/benhuntington/teach/teach-project/)

Using your XML file, this would generate a scatter plot like this:

[image]